# In CodeIgniter, how to display a view page in a particular div element

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, codeigniter

This is how I'm calling my dashboard view from controller. I want to display some page (e.g. the index page) in the div element instead of it opening in a new tab.

```php
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('index');
}

public function dashboard() {
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
}
```

I got stuck in the UI part on a project using CodeIgniter. I need to display a view page inside a div element, but instead of displaying in the div either it is getting displayed in the new tab or nothing is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.aboutus').click(function(){
     $('#about').load('controller/method');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your controller method how you're printing view?

Comment: ...and the HTML for that js-snippet.

Comment: i recommend you to use ajax.

Comment: @SaadSuri i have edited the post you can check that, i have provide i link

Comment: you're loading view but not printing the view [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164599/loading-a-view-after-an-ajax-call-codeigniter#answer-30885286)

Comment: @SaadSuri is mandatory to use? Coz i want display static page in the div

Comment: yes because if you're not printing any data how can jquery ajax know what you want to display

Comment: We need to see the HTML. Is `.aboutus` a link (`<a href...>`)? I suspect it is and that the browser is just following the link when you click it. If so, you'll need to prevent the default click behaviour - `$('.aboutus').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); ....`)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.aboutus').click(function(){
     //$('#about').load('controller/method');
     $('#about').load('<?php echo site_url('controller/method'); ?>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show your dashboard html page? and #about html too

Comment: I mean HTML code of your main page and HTML code which you want to call via ajax AND can you tell me from your console, what are you getting when you click .aboutus class is there jquery error or nothing

Comment: Possibly worth adding `event.preventDefault()` to your example in case the OP is has this click event attached to a link.