# Page not redirecting with data in Codeigniter using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Passing value from anchor tag on `click` event to controller `product_show()` value store in variable. But page was not load. But it will show in NETWORK(RESPONSE) with all data.

**HTML** `<a code>`:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/product_show" class="bar_text"
    value="Sugar&Jaggery">Sugar &amp; Jaggery</a>
```

**AJAX** pass `value="Sugar&Jaggery"` on `click` event to controller:

```
$('.bar_text').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Home/product_show',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'value':value},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Not Work');
        },
    });
});
```

**Controller** get value in way variable via AJAX and pass it to model for getting data from database. But `display_product` can't show in front but it will show in NETWORK(RESPONSE) with all data.

```
public function product_show(){
   $way =array('Subcategory_name'=>$this->input->post('value'));
   $data['testdata']= $this->Globle_model->get_multiple_record($way);
   $this->load->view('display_product',$data);
}
```

**Model** value get in `$type_arrat` variable get data from database and return to controller.

```
public function get_multiple_record($type_array){  
    $this->db->where_in('Subcategory_name',$type_array);
    $get_data = $this->db->get('productmaster');
    return $get_data->result_array();
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have verified that everything is working - `value` is correctly passed back to your controller, and your back end code is correctly finding records, but the final view is not displaying?  That's bcs you are trying to return a CI view to your JS success function.  If you want the rendered view *data* in your JS, [use the 3rd parameter in your `view()` call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164599/loading-a-view-after-an-ajax-call-codeigniter/30885286). If you want to redirect, you will need something like `window.location.href` in your JS.

Comment: try to run code in that .but getting error Message: Call to undefined method Home::set_output()

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 may be in ajax Call issue so use:

```
 php echo base_url('Controller/Function');
```

Case 2 is you may use this in success method:

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('Controller/Function') ?>";
```